# Is using "this" keyword with every class variable of class is good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, this

I just want to know using **this keyword** with class variable in class is good practice or bad?

if I use **this** will it reduce or increase Run time/compile time of application?
like below :-

```
this.FirsName = cust.name;
this.LastName = cust.Lname;
this.Age = cust.age;
this.DOB = cust.dob;
```

and so on for more than 1000 lines code...

Comment: I'd say the actual problem is when you really have 1000 lines of trivial copy code like that -- this suggests prudent use of Automapper or a redesign of classes is in order, never mind your `this` qualifying.

Comment: I'd be astonished if it made any measurable difference to the compile-time performance. But if that's what you're concerned about, can't you try to measure it yourself? Build it lots of times *with* `this.`, and then again after doing a search and replace to remove it (with some care to ensure there aren't semantic changes), then build it lots of times again. I'd expect the readability (which is more subjective) to be far more important than the compile time here.

Comment: You should ask that question to your dev-team, not to us. Companies may have different code-styles.

Comment: Why do you even care for compile-time? How often do you build your projects that this may have an effect at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wont effect your compile time, or your run time. 
it's not a good practice neither.

the reason for using `this` keyword is to separate between class props then to another properties inside a particular section.

If your talking about code convention and styling, just adopt Microsofts one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions

you should read Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this

Comment: "it's not a good practice neither" That´s not entirely true. Although there´s no difference in a semantic way or for the compiler, there may be some advantage for readers of the code. Having said this the question is completely opinion-based.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_